# Bootstrap gradient background not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, gradient

I have a background gradient for the hamburger icon in my navbar.
As you can see in the snippet result it has some strange "borders" on left and right.

How can I make these borders disappear?

```css
.btn-primary {
  border-color: transparent !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  background: #0080eb;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,#0080eb 0,#00d3eb 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  padding: 0 9px !important;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 13px -10px rgba(0,128,235,.75);
}
.bg-primary.container {
  background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="wrapper-navbar" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite" class="fixed-top white-transp-gradient">

  <a class="skip-link sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">Salta al contenuto</a>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-primary container">

      <button class="navbar-toggler btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
      <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul id="main-menu" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home active menu-item-13 nav-item"><a title="Home" href="http://example.test/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>

      </ul>
</div>     
     
   </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->

  </div>
```

Comment: It is `border` issue, add `border: 0 !important` and it works

Comment: yes! it was only that... I didn't set a border, so I thought it was something else... Thank you!

Comment: add `background-clip: padding-box;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `border` issue, add `border: 0 !important` and it works, check below:-

```css
.btn-primary {
  border-color: transparent !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #0080eb;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,#0080eb 0,#00d3eb 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  padding: 0 9px !important;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 13px -10px rgba(0,128,235,.75);
  border: 0 !important;
}
.bg-primary.container {
  background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="wrapper-navbar" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite" class="fixed-top white-transp-gradient">

  <a class="skip-link sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">Salta al contenuto</a>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-primary container">

      <button class="navbar-toggler btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
      <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul id="main-menu" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home active menu-item-13 nav-item"><a title="Home" href="http://example.test/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>

      </ul>
</div>     
     
   </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->

  </div>
```